# Hovering over an icon-only list menu item and ease out hidden text from right-to-left

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have to create a list menu that is only icons and when you hover over it, the hidden text eases out right to left. Unfortunately I don't know transitions well enough to accomplish this.  What I currently have transitions out, but the whole menu comes with it. Here's a snippet of what I mean

https://codepen.io/onesneakymofo/pen/qBdxyjB

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="hide-me">Users</span>
      <span class="fas fa-list fa-user fa-2x fa-inverse icon"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="hide-me">Email</span>
      <span class="fas fa-list fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-inverse icon"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="hide-me">Settings</span>
      <span class="fas fa-list fa-cog  fa-2x fa-inverse icon"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;

}

ul {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 25px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  top: 5px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 25px;
}


.hide-me{
  font-size: 26px;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover{
  top: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
  width: 125px;
}

li:hover .hide-me { 
    opacity: 100;
    transition: opacity .35s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}

li:hover .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

The closest thing that I have found to what I want is

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52211712

but when I try to make it into a list, the same thing from my snippet happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::after` and `position:absolute` to put content behind your menu, and `:hover::after` to then move it out from behind.  The relevant CSS is in the head of the HTML below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      li {
        background-color: white;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      li::after {
        content: "12345";
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        z-index: -1;
      }
      li:hover::after {
        left: 200px;
        transition: all 1s ease;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>qwertyuiop asdf</li>
      <br>
      <li>qwertyuiop asdf</li>
      <br>
      <li>qwertyuiop asdf</li>
      <br>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```