# Display slider like drawer on clicking box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two boxes. Now when the user clicks on LeftToRight then I have to slide content from left to right with LeftToRight box. If the user clicks on RightToLeft the I have to slide the div from right to left.

I tried below code but it's not displaying properly when clicking on the button. I want like a drawer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickLeft").click(function() {
    $(".leftoRightbox").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    });

    if (!$('.innerWrapper').hasClass("hidesecondbox")) {
      $('.innerWrapper').addClass('hidesecondbox');
    } else {
      $('.innerWrapper').removeClass('hidesecondbox');
    }
  });
  $("#clickRight").click(function() {
    $(".righttoLeftbox").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    });

    if (!$('.innerWrapper').hasClass("hidefirstbox")) {
      $('.innerWrapper').addClass('hidefirstbox');
    } else {
      $('.innerWrapper').removeClass('hidefirstbox');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.innerWrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.displayflex {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftoRightbox,
.righttoLeftbox,
.goback,
.hidefirstbox .one,
.hidesecondbox .two {
  display: none;
}

.leftoRightbox,
.righttoLeftbox {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="innerWrapper">


    <div class="displayflex one">
      <div class="leftoRightbox">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="leftoRight box" id="clickLeft">
        <h2>This is slide left to right</h2>
        <p class="goback">Go Back</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="displayflex two">
      <div class="righttoLeft box" id="clickRight">
        <h2>This is slide right to left</h2>
        <p class="goback">Go Back</p>
      </div>
      <div class="righttoLeftbox">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex-shrink:0;` to box element and define a fixed width for the `p` element to avoid the bad effect when doing the animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickLeft").click(function() {
    $(".leftoRightbox").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    });

    if (!$('.innerWrapper').hasClass("hidesecondbox")) {
      $('.innerWrapper').addClass('hidesecondbox');
    } else {
      $('.innerWrapper').removeClass('hidesecondbox');
    }
  });
  $("#clickRight").click(function() {
    $(".righttoLeftbox").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    });

    if (!$('.innerWrapper').hasClass("hidefirstbox")) {
      $('.innerWrapper').addClass('hidefirstbox');
    } else {
      $('.innerWrapper').removeClass('hidefirstbox');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.innerWrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.displayflex {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftoRightbox,
.righttoLeftbox,
.goback,
.hidefirstbox .one,
.hidesecondbox .two {
  display: none;
}
.leftoRightbox p,
.righttoLeftbox p{
  width:calc(100vw - 280px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="innerWrapper">


    <div class="displayflex one">
      <div class="leftoRightbox">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="leftoRight box" id="clickLeft">
        <h2>This is slide left to right</h2>
        <p class="goback">Go Back</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="displayflex two">
      <div class="righttoLeft box" id="clickRight">
        <h2>This is slide right to left</h2>
        <p class="goback">Go Back</p>
      </div>
      <div class="righttoLeftbox">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```